# What's the most basic jQuery implementation of a multi-category dropdown menu?

Tags: jquery, menu

I'm looking for a HORIZONTAL jQuery dropdown menu that presents multiple sub categories.

I'll give a VERTICAL example because it's easier to represent here:

```
-> a
    -> a1
    -> a2
-> b
    -> b1
        -> b1a
    -> b2
-> c
    -> c2
        -> c2a
            -> c2a1
            -> c2a2
```

If you drop your left ear towards your left shoulder, you can imagine what this would look like from the top of a page :)

Comment: You don't even need Javascript: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below links -

http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/

http://apycom.com/menus/5-black.html

You can google out for more of them.